# SQL order by 2 columns

Tags: mysql

i have a table with 2 columns that contain either text or just `1`

I want to execute a simple `SELECT * FROM` query on the table and order by the 2 columns

Some rows will have one column blank and others will not have any columns blank but i want to display the rows with either one or both columns that contain text at the bottom of my results

Sample Data:

```
sequence = 1
col1 = 'hello'
col2 = 'hello'

sequence = 2
col1 = ''
col2 = ''

sequence = 3
col1 = 'hello'
col2 = ''
```

so the above data should display in the order (by sequence):

```
2
3
1
```

Comment: If you had sequence = 3, col1 = '', col2 = 'hello'  where should that appear in the result sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly count the number of blanks and use that for ordering:

```
order by ((col1 = '') + (col2 = '')) desc
```

This counts the number of values.

Note:  if the values are really `NULL` and not empty strings, then:

```
order by ((col1 is null) + (col2 is null)) desc
```

Both of these use the MySQL feature that a boolean expression is treated as an integer in a numeric context, with 1 for true and 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional ordering :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.col1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
         CASE WHEN t.col2 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
         t.col1,t.col2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
ORDER BY 
        col1 ASC
        , col2 ASC
```

you could even limit it

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
ORDER BY 
        col1 ASC LIMIT 3
        , col2 ASC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY col1, col2 ASC/DESC;`.